# using SSE ( Server Sent Events ) with multiple Spring boot instances

Tags: spring-boot, concurrency, scaling, server-sent-events, concurrenthashmap

I'm working on a project using Server Sent Events with Spring Boot.

I receive a Rest Call from a Webservice then i want to dispatch the event to one specific Client.

I use 3 instances of the Spring boot MicroService, When a client is subscribed i store the related SseEmitter it in a Map with a client Id.

When i will Receive the event from external WS, how can i call the right instance containing the Map where the targeted client SseEmitter is stored ? Because if i call an instance where the client didn't use to subscribe i won't find my SseEmitter.

Can i share a concurrentHashMap between multiple instance of Spring boot microservices ?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this ?

Comment: @Firu finally i used Kafka for this need, i have hesitated between RabitMQ and Kafka but finally kafka is working well on this project.